# connect google bigquery from onprem using python

Tags: google-bigquery

We have our application hosted on Google Cloud and their logs are being uploaded to Google Bigquery Datasets.

We want to fetch the monitoring data from an On-Prem Server using Python program and create a dashboard using those data points.

How can I connect to Google BigQuery from On Prem and how to fetch data using Python.

Thanks,

Adi

Comment: Do you want to know how to talk to BigQuery via its REST Api?

Comment: Yes. What setup do I need to make in my local onprem Linux machine where I can run a python program to run bigquery to fetch data points from BQ datasets and create my custom graph.

Answer (score 0):

This is all documented on the [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api#authorizing) page, also with Python examples provided.

Comment: I tried to follow that but Its failing. I launched a new instance . Enabled all APIs for that instance. Ssh to that instance and switched to Python. Ran credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()   but this is not working. Then I tried >>> from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named oauth2client.client
>>>
Many people facing this issue. How to start thats no where mentioned. https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/stable/gcloud-auth.html

Comment: post the error you are getting. Also did you run "gcloud auth login" ?